# Return back dropped(deleted) table Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I accidentally deleted table "results" from schema with this command in rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:results)
```

I tried but not working

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=201608021358
```

How can I take it back? I just want the structure not the data

Please help!

Comment: try `rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=my_version`

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "results" does not exist

Comment: please update your migration file to get more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dropped the table directly without migration so there is no neat way.

Comment everything from `down` method from `201608021358_xxxx.rb` assuming this migration is `create_results`

Reason for commenting the code is "Your migration is still `UP` as you haven't done it through migration" and if you `UP` it it will not do anything while `DOWN` will give you error saying `results table doesn't exist`

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=201608021358
rake db:migrate:up VERSION=201608021358
```

that will solve the issue

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  table "results" does not exist

Comment: can you please post the migration

Comment: if you have `change` method in migration for now rename it to `up` and create a empty method `down`

Comment: welcome, once done remember to revert the changes you did in the migration file